# using viewWithTag for a view inside a cell that's inside a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

This is my layout:
I have a TableView -> Cell - > Inside the cell I have some `UITextField`s and a `UIView` with a few more `UITextField`s. When I want to fill them with data inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I've created a simple for loop to fill them all. My problem is that I can't access the `UITextField` inside the separate `UIView` using `viewWithTag` (I don't want to assign each and every one of them by their outlet name, that's why I'm using the for loop).

So this code will only work on the `UITextField`s that are inside the cell but not on the `UITextField`s that are inside the view that is inside the cell:

```
for (int i=1;i<15;i++)
{
    UITextField *temp = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
    temp.text = @"something";
}
```

Another thing that I don't understand is that if I log the `UITextField` I can see that it's filled with data but I don't see it on screen.

```
        UITextField *temp = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:8]; //8 is a tag for a `UITexiField inside the view that is in the cell 
        NSLog(@"temp: %@",temp);
        temp.text = @"something";
        NSLog(@"temp: %@",temp);

baseClass = UITextField; frame = (0 12; 35 35); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 8; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7578650>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7577650>>

baseClass = UITextField; frame = (0 12; 35 35); text = 'something'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 8; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7578650>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7577650>>
```

But I won't see it on screen.

Comment: Is `self.view` is the view with the textfields?

Comment: Well no, self.view is the main view. Inside that there is the tableview , the cell and inside that another view. in that view the problematic text fields exists.

Comment: Can you try using contentView of the cell, for fetching views using tag ?

Answer (score 0):

1. After you assign `temp`, then you have to iterate through the view `UITextField` and `UIView` in `temp` to get through what you want.
2. Are you adding them as a `subview`? Normally that is why they don't show up even thought he content is there as below:

   ```
   [self.view addSubview:temp];
   ```

Comment: Everything is done in the IB. No need to add `addSubview` to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Download the category available [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/ViewUtils)

Use the method

```
- (NSArray *)viewsWithTag:(NSInteger)tag;
```

Make sure u have the same tag number for all the text field as the method returns array.